# Code Behind can't find a nested SQL connection in a List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have one ListView nested in another one as follows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="editorMenuLinks" OnDataBound="ListView1_DataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="test2" DataKeyNames="ID_connection" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
        </asp:ListView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="test2">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test2.SelectParameters["-------"].DefaultValue = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();        
}
```

Unfortunately the SqlDataSource test2 can't be found in code behind. I get an error that the connection (test2) doesn't exist in the current context. Any tip?

Thanks

Comment: If I put it outside the SQL control parameters will not work.I've tried it before and the nested control parameters couldn't be found....

Comment: Looks like ListView2 contains the same data in every item of ListView1(?). I'd create a dataset and use it as the datasource of ListView2 in the RowDataBound event of ListView1

Answer (score 0):

You can find controls inside the listview by doing

```
 Listview1.FindControl("Name of Control")
```

Assign this to an instance of a sqlDataSource for example.

```
Dim Test2 as SqlDataSource = Listview1.FindControl("Test2")
```